# Why do we write " -> Void " in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

According to Apple's documentation, you can write a function both like:

```
func printHelloWorld() {
print("hello, world")
}
```

And:

```
func printHelloWorld() -> Void {
print("hello, world")
}
```

But since they are the same, and simplicity makes code beautiful, why do people sometimes still write the `-> Void` ?

Comment: I think because they like to write `->Void`,just personal style,nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Writing `-> Void` makes it explicit.

Comment: And explicit code is good. It tells me that the author of the func wanted to return Void and didn't just forget to write the return type.